# How can I get a list of tree-ancestors and tree-descendants from this d3.js layout.tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, tree

I'm experimenting with and modifying [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example of d3.js to draw a tree based on a JSON tree structure. This is what part of the tree looks like to start out with:

I'm trying to make 2 separate modifications, but I don't know how to do them:

1. When the text of a node is clicked, I want to get a collection of the text elements of all the tree-descendants. I want to do this so that I can toggle their style classes between `my-old-class` and `my-new-class`.
2. When the text of a node is clicked, I want to get a collection of the text elements of all the tree-ancestors. I want to do this so that I can toggle their style classes between `my-old-class` and `my-new-class`.

How can I do it?

I don't know at all how to do #1 at all other than I need to add an on-click function to the `nodeEnter.append("text")` statement. But what should that function do?

For #2, I know this is the relevant part of the code I need to modify. Something like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .on("click", function(d) {
        for (var currentAncestor = this.parentNode; /* WHAT EXPRESSION GOES HERE?? */; currentAncestor = currentAncestor.parentNode) {
            var ancestorText = /* WHAT EXPRESSION GOES HERE?? */;
            ancestorText.classed("my-new-class", !ancestorText.classed("my-new-class"));
            ancestorText.classed("my-old-class", !ancestorText.classed("my-old-class"));
  });
```

But I'm not sure what to put in place of those two expressions such that I properly loop through the text elements **only** of the tree's ancestors (not the DOM ancestors!!)

**EDIT:**

As an example, in the screenshot below, when the user clicks on the text "data", I want its ancestors text ("vis" and "flare") and its descendants text (every word that appears to the right of "data" to become red)

[image]

Comment: Not clear put a screen shot of what you want..

Comment: Sorry Cyril. Screenshot and a bit more explanation added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Each node should have a parent like this:

```
  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(function(child){
        child.parent = d;//so now each node will have a parent except root node.
      });      
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }
```

Next a function to set the color. 
This function will iterate through the given node and set its children to have a color field.

```
function setColor(d, color) {
  d.color= color;
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(function(d){setColor(d,color)});
  } else if(d._children){
    d._children.forEach(function(d){setColor(d,color)});
  }
}
```

On text click call this function:

```
function textClick(d) {
  setColor(root, "black");//set all the nodes to have black.
  d1 = d;
  //iterate over all its parent and make it red
  while(d1){
    d1.color = "red";
    d1 = d1.parent;
  }
  //set color of the children node to red.
  setColor(d, "red")
  update(root);//call update so that the node text color is colored accordingly.
}
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7qAh5rZQtSB2kvz51Gjx?p=preview)