# How can I change style class & content of text for ancestors in this d3.js tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, tree

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292914/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-tree-ancestors-and-tree-descendants-from-this-d3-js-layo). (Thanks Cyril for all your help!!)

My problem turned out to be a little bit tricker and I still need some help.
When the user clicks on a text element of any node, I would like the following to happen:

- For each tree-ancestor of that element:

  - Append "X" to that text element
  - Remove the style class "class1" from that element
  - Add the style class "class2" from that element
  - Disable the onclick method from that element
- During these steps other nodes should remain completely untouched.

I have added the `parent` item to the Object representing the data in `collapse()` as Cyril recommended. So I can traverse up the path to root. However as I traverse this path, I cannot get a hold of the d3.js element for the text. How can I do that? Once I do that, the above operations will be relatively simple for me to do.

Below is an illustrated example of what I want. When the user clicks `Visualizations`, `viz` and `flare` should become `vizX` and `flareX`. Their style classes should be switched from `class1` to `class2`. And clicking on the `vizX` and `flareX` texts should have no effect. ***And no other nodes should be updated in any way.***

How can I do it? I need to be able to grab the d3.js drawing elements as I traverse through the tree.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you traverse up from the node clicked, to the parent root.

You can also get the DOM element (group which has the circle and text) for the data like shown in the function below.

```
function findNode(text){
  var DOM = d3.selectAll(".node")[0].find(function(node){
    return (d3.select(node).data()[0].name == text);
  })
  return DOM;
}
```

So now when ever you have the data and you want to find the group it associates to.

You can make use of the above function and call.

```
  var k = findNode("physics");//this will return the DOM which has the node physics.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I got the DOM element from the data object by doing `var domElement = findNode("flare");` In the dev console, I can see the HTML that makes up that domElement. But when I try to do `var x = domElement.select("text");`, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: domElement.select is not a function`

Comment: ok do this please d3.select(domElement).select("text"). **Reason** domElement returned by the function is just html DOM so you need to select it and then select the text it contains.

Comment: What am I doing wrong here? The following still doesn't change the text: `var textElement = d3.select(self.findNode(d)).select("text")[0]; console.log("textElement = ", textElement); textElement.textContent = d.name + "X";`
`

Comment: how about this `var text = d3.select(self.findNode(d)).select("text").text();
d3.select(self.findNode(d)).select("text").text(text + "-X");`

Comment: YES! Thanks very much