# How to initially make only selected nodes in this d3.js expanded?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js, tree

I'm experimenting with and modifying [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example of d3.js to draw a tree based on a JSON structure.

This tree starts out with the root node expanded, and all other nodes contracted.

But I want to modify it by passing in JSON array that is exemplified here:

```
expandedNodes = ["analytics", "flare", "graph", "scale"]
```

if `expandedNodes` is empty, I want the tree to start off in the position it already does (with only the root node expanded).

If `expandedNodes` is non-empty I want the tree to start out with only those nodes expanded that appear in `expandededNodes` (in this example as shown in the picture below)

[image]

How do I do it?

You can assume that

- The `findNode()` function written by Cyril [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370595/1742777) is available.
- All nodes in the tree have unique names
- The array `expandedNodes` is valid such that if a node's name appears in it, so do all of it's ancestors names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
  //array of expanded nodes
  expandedNodes = ["analytics", "flare", "graph", "scale"];
  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      //if node present in expanded nodes array keep it open.
      if (expandedNodes.find(function(d1){ return d1 == d.name})){
        //expanded nodes children should be collapsed.
        d.children.forEach(collapse);
        return;
      }
      d.children.forEach(function(child){
        child.parent = d;
      });      
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SAVs3S1v2R53eSbCuXCm?p=preview)